# Symfony 2.0.3 Global template variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I've got an Entity that I want to associate with the users session.
I created a service so that I could reach this info from where ever.

in the service i save the entities id in an session variable
and in the `getEntity()` method i get the session variable and with doctrine find the entity and return it.

this way to the template i should be able to call `{{ myservice.myentity.myproperty }}`

The problem is that myservice is used all over the place, and I don't want to have to get it in every since Action and append it to the view array.

Is there a way to make a service accessible from all views like the session `{{ app.session }}` ?

Comment: After some googling I found a couple of leeds. Either I could add something like this, but where? `$twig->addGlobal('myservice', $this->get('myservice'));` or I could utilize the event system in symfony to do a `FilterResponseEvent`and somehow add the service to the Response variables there? any suggestions?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## The solution

By creating a custom service i can get to that from where ever by using

```
$this->get('myservice');
```

this is all done by http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

But I'll give you some demo code.

### The Service

This first snippet is the actual service

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\AppBundle\Extensions;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use MyBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Patient;

class AppState
{
    protected $session;
    protected $em;

    function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getPatient()
    {
        $id = $this->session->get('patient');
        return isset($id) ? $em->getRepository('MyBundleStoreBundle:Patient')->find($id) : null;
    }
}
```

Register it in you `config.yml` with something like this

```
services:
    appstate:
        class: MyBundle\AppBundle\Extensions\AppState
        arguments: [@session, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Now we can as I said before, get the service in our controllers with

```
$this->get('myservice');
```

But since this is a global service I didn't want to have to do this in every controller and every action

```
public function myAction()
{
    $appstate = $this->get('appstate');
    return array(
        'appstate' => $appstate
    );
}
```

so now we go create a Twig_Extension

### Twig Extension

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\AppBundle\Extensions;

use MyBundle\AppBundle\Extensions\AppState;

class AppStateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $appState;

    function __construct(AppState $appState) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
    }

    public function getGlobals() {
        return array(
            'appstate' => $this->appState
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appstate';
    }

}
```

By using dependency injection we now have the AppState Service that we created in the twig extension named appstate

Now we register that with the symfony (again inside the `services` section inside the config-file)

```
twig.extension.appstate:
    class: MyBundle\AppBundle\Extensions\AppStateExtension
    arguments: [@appstate]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

The important part being the "tags", since this is what symfony uses to find all twig extensions

We are now set to use our appstate in our twig templates by the variable name

```
{{ appstate.patient }}
```

or

```
{{ appstate.getPatient() }}
```

Awesome!

Comment: Please consider creating a cookbook article from this answer in the Sf2 docs.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot. I'll use it in Jobeet for Symfony 2 tutorial that I am creating in displaying user jobs history (:

Comment: I still find the services a bit cumbersome to set up but one they're ready, they're a nice clean solution! Thank you for your guide!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this in your action ? : $this->container->get('templating')->addGlobal($name, $value)

Comment: That sounds like the right symfony way to get $twig, the questing still lies, since i have over 30 controllers, I need to add this in one place. Should i use the autoloader?

Comment: I usually use a parent controller (e.g. BaseController ) for each bundle and create other controller extending that. Inserting a global variable using this solution will be easy if you use similar pattern.

Comment: I had a listener subscribed to the `kernel.request` event that called `addGlobal()`. However eventually down the line, one of the third-party bundles has extended Twig to use a service that relied on the session. This meant the session had been started early before Symfony's TestSessionListener kicked in and tests wouldn't run at all. Registering a Twig Extension solved the problem. I thought I'd share this because it took me ages to figure out!