# Symfony 2 + Twig global variables

Tags: symfony, twig

How can one get a twig global variable to maintain modification after changing it with includes?  My desired output is "set @ deeper" though I get "original setting".

app/config/config.yml

```
twig:
    globals:
      testvar: "original setting"
```

root.html.twig

```
{% include "MyBundle::levelone.html.twig" %}
{{ testvar }}
```

levelone.html.twig

```
{% set testvar = "set @ levelone" %}
{% include "MyBundle::deeper.html.twig" %}
```

deeper.html.twig

```
{% set testvar = "set @ deeper" %}
```

Comment: Have you tried within blocks ? I mean, wrap all your `{% set testvar %}` and `{{ testvar }}` with `{%block global_test %}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question and I don't know an answer but no amount fooling around with blocks and stuff will work.  I looked in the generated php cache template files.  When you echo a variable it looks like:

```
// {{ testvar }}
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getContext($context, "testvar"), "html", null, true);
```

So basically it first looks for testvar in your local context.  If not found then it looks in the global context.

When you set the value of test var you get:

```
// {% set testvar = 'level one' }}
$context["testvar"] = "level one";
```

So only the local context gets updated.  The changed value goes away when the included template returns.

So by default at least it looks like global variables are really read only.

It might be possible to do this through an extension.  I don't know enough about the internals.

Answer (score 8):

From a container aware object :

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('ThomasDecauxIsAwsome', 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to define a global variable through Twig? You can do it in your config.yml file as follows:

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_global_var : myvalue
```

So `{{my_global_var}}` in your template will print `myvalue`

For more info read the [official docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals).

Comment: how do I have to put those 2 lines: "$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('text', new Text());" in my symfony2.1 project?

Comment: Well, I'm not using Symfony2.1 yet, since it is a beta release. However, I can say that with Symfony2.016 you can define a global variable in your config.yml file as provided [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html).

Comment: the fact is that in this way the variable is readonly, I mean, in a template you can change its value, but when you access it from another template, you'll find that its value is now the default one set in the config.yml

Comment: If you are interested to change the value only for the current user, you can read it once and store it in a session variable. If you need to change the value for all the users, then use a database.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by defining a **Twig Extension** via **Services**, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658366/184176)