# How can I define global variables inside a twig template file?

Tags: php, variables, twig, global, templating

Is it possible to set global variables in a twig file, so that I can access that variables from other files, macros and blocks.

For example, I want to have `variables.twig` file and in it set my variables and then I can include it in other templates.

I know that setting global variables is possible from the framework (e.g. Symfony) but I want a solution using twig features only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2 + Twig global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263903/symfony-2-twig-global-variables)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Using Symfony configuration

If you are using Symfony2+, you can set globals in your `config.yml` file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        myStuff: %someParam%
```

And then use `{{ myStuff }}` anywhere in your application.

---

## Using Twig_Environment::addGlobal

If you are using Twig in another project, you can set your globals directly in the environment:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('myStuff', $someVariable);
```

And then use `{{ myStuff }}` anywhere in your application.

---

## Using a Twig template

When you're including a piece of Twig code, you're only including the rendered view coming from that code, not the code itself. So it is by design not possible to include a set of variables the way you are looking for.

Comment: If I use the second method, do I set this once and it persists through my application like $_SESSION or do I need to do this every time twig is initialized?

Comment: Can't you just call a function from twig (ie. {{ function('do_global_things') }}, and access globals in the function? I only skimmed the question and answer so maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: @JoelM you may but it breaks Twig's general design and is all but secure. It's as beautiful as writing html in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Since **Symfony 4**, you can set the globals in `config/packages/twig.yaml`.

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        ga_tracking: 'UA-xxxxx-x'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can assign global READONLY variables in your top-level template and use them in all underlying templates. But you can't override them of course.
It covers my case, maybe will be useful for somebody else.

> base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{# assign global vars here #}
{% set myReadonlyJar = your_custom_ext_twig_function() %} 
<html>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

> my_page.twig

```
{% extends 'stack/base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ myReadonlyJar.v1 }}

    {{ myReadonlyJar.v2 }}
    {{ include('stack/deep.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

> deep.twig

```
Check top vars very deep inside: <br>
{{ myReadonlyJar.v2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SlimFramework` and `Twig-View:3.0`

You can use the following method `Twig::offsetSet`

```
$twig = Twig::create('view/templates');
$twig->offsetSet('globalVar', 'globalVarValue');
```