# Symfony2: Solution for repeating a code within each new controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I've a piece of code that repeats within each controller in `DefaultController.php` which annoys me a lot. Can I put it once somewhere instead of copy-past it in each new Controller I add?

Answer (score 3):

If the code should be run at the beginning of each controller action I'd recommend writing a handler for  [KernelEvent](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events) `kernel.controller` Event that fires before the code is dispatched to the controllers.

If the code should be run somewhere in the action code, you could [create your own event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) and create a handler for it. You can append the controller and all needed data to your custom event object.

Comment: I may not be understanding the question but if you just trying to avoid copy/pasting code then have DefaultController extend the Symfony controller and then have your individual controllers extend DefaultController.  But I'm guessing (as @chiborg said) that you really want to execute some repetitive code.

Comment: Well, what I need is to get the session and send it to the template, this is the repetitive code in each Controller:
`$session = $this->get('session'); $foo = $session->get('uid');  return $this->render('template',array('session' => $foo));` unless there's another way of getting and sending the session to the template :). thanks.

Comment: In this case, a Twig extension is probably a better way. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647602/symfony-2-0-3-global-template-variable

Comment: Or you could just use `{{ app.session.uid }}` See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#global-template-variables

Comment: Great, I understand now. Actually, I've twig (page.html.twig) and php (page.html.php) pages, how to call the session object within a php file please?

Comment: Have never tried to use PHP templates, but try the following: Check if the `$app` var is initialized in your template (just do a `var_export($app);` in your template code. Alternatively check what's in the `$view` variable, maybe you find something there.

Comment: I think it'd better to make another post to ask about the php template code. Thank u very much Chiborg.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same thing.

to manage permission in each action of a controller, i am calling a service

```
$this->permissions =$this->get('vendor.permissions')->checkPermission('BundleName','Profil','select',$this);
```